# Word for a number that has all the same digits

Tags: single-word-requests

In Metropolis, all bus routes are numbered with a number >10, but not all numbers are used.

Buses 33, 55, 222, and the special 55555, and only those buses, go to the airport.  All the buses that go to the airport, and only those buses, are numbered such that all digits are the same.   The local taxi service (phone #777-7777) also goes to the airport.

What is a concise way of describing a number with multiple digits that are all the same digit?

Under 100, I would call them "multiples of 11."   Is there a word for the more general class, narrower than "palindrome?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are known as ***[repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit)***.

The article states it is implicitly valid for at least base 10, but it easily generalises for all bases:

eg:

- bin **111** = 7 (which is a repdigit either way)
- hex **CCC** = 3276
- oct **777** = 511

With **x** being the digit to be repeated, **B** the base and **y** the number of repeats, in base **10** a repdigit can be calculated thusly:

[image]

Comment: There is also the potential that: a. I think that capitalising is appropriate in this case, and b. It's some form of typo. In this case it's more the latter, I copied and pasted it from wikipedia directly  :)

Comment: Interesting. But how well known generally? Most dictionaries that have it say that its usage is in "recreational mathematics".  Several mainstream dictionaries (Merriam-Webster, Collins, Oxford Dictionaries) don't list it at all.  So it might not be commonly used among transit system administrators (or riders!)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to spell it out, say, as "repeated digit number"; The  "digit" being singular, because the same digit repeats (rather than several digits repeating as in the fraction 1/7  = 0.1428571428571428...)

Comment: It seems to me that bin 111 = 7, not 8.

Comment: True! Not sure how that sneaked in 

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_(cricket)). 222 is called Two Nelson and 333 is called Three Nelson

Comment: What about 33 and 55?

Comment: I was able to verify "Nelson", so I added a link for that (but I didn't find "two Nelson", only "double Nelson"). It's definitely not a term I've heard before; can you add any evidence it's used outside cricket?